# Firefox Command+K no longer opens search

Tags: keyboard, search, firefox

In Firefox, pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> used to open a search page. But as of recent updates, it only focuses the URL bar.

I have the search bar hidden... so this sort of makes sense. However when I want to search for something with periods in it, Firefox treats it as a URL. For example: `document.getElementById()`.

Is there a way to restore the old <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> functionality of opening a true search field?

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help. It looks like a bug with firefox. I went to file the bug at bugzilla, and saw this is a regression from 3 years ago. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950014

Comment: @patrix, I found Phong's answer to be the best and most appropriate. It restored CMD+K to a dedicated search. The only con is it requires at least the firefox menu item to be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching from the URL bar, I prepend a space before search terms containing a `.`. This forces Firefox not to treat the first two words as a domain name. This has worked since even before Firefox 1.0.

In your case though, make sure you have the **Search Bar** in Firefox’s drawer/“hamburger” menu. Pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> focuses that search bar for me, without needing to drag it onto the application’s main toolbar.

[image: Search Menu]

If the **Search Bar** is missing, open that same menu, and click **Customize**. Drag the **Search Bar** from the collection of **Additional Tools and Features** onto your “hamburger” menu.

[image: Customize Menu]

If the **Search Bar** isn’t available from there, you may need to **Restore Defaults**.

Comment: That does work, and it's the closest I can get to the original functionality. However for me that menu is opening on top of the browser window, making it not useful, it's off screen.

Comment: I moved the menu button around, restarted firefix, and now it seems to work OK. Thank you @Phong!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, in that it allows you to search in the URL bar for things that Firefox interprets as URLs.

1. Hit Command+K
2. Enter `document.getElementById()`
3. Hit the TAB key (or the down key) once to change selection from `http://document.getElementById() - Visit` to `document.getElementById() - Search with Google`
4. Hit ENTER

Comment: That's fine for CMD+L but I want the dedicated search field back for CMD+K.

Comment: I'm confused. You want the dedicated search field back, but only when you hit CMD+K?

Comment: Yes. Command+K used to show the firefox start page. It showed the search field in the middle with the cursor already focused.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't make the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> keyboard shortcut take you to the dedicated search field is because it's not there. So, it now comes to a decision between learning how to use the URL field to conduct the search you want, or getting the dedicated search bar back?

Here are your two options:

1. Leave it as is and when you conduct a search for something that has periods in it, just use quotation marks. So, instead os searching for `document.getElementById()`, you search for `"document.getElementById()"` instead.
2. Restore the default toolbar by going to **View > Toolbars > Customize...** and in the window that appears, select the Restore Defaults option at bottom-right. This will make the dedicated search field present and allow the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> keyboard shortcut to work as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. However this is not what I was looking for. In a recent previous version of FF the search field did not have to be visible for Command+K to run a dedicated search.

Comment: In that case, can you clarify how it _did_ work? For example, you have FF open at some website and decide to press Command+K, what happens? Did a dedicated search field appear in the toolbar? Did a popup window appear? Something else? It's not clear to me _how_ it worked if the dedicated search wasn't in your toolbar to begin with.

Comment: Aah, I'v just seen your comment to Alistair's answer. So Command+K used to just open the FF start page. Hmm...